# How can I run a batch script from java on a remote windows machine

Tags: java, linux, windows, batch-file, ssh

I have a machine that runs batch scripts over ssh on windows machine using open ssh and cygwin (copssh)
I'm looking to change this mechanism since this tool requires configuration where many mistakes can be made.
I will also need to collect the results of the script
Any ideas on how it can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use RMI and on the remote side just use Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Comment: I can't run my code on the remote side only use standard configuration

Comment: So u are only allowed to out your script there, nothing else?

Comment: in addition to the script, is there either cygwin or at least a java virtual machine available?

Comment: Its a batch script running on windows. I don't want to install anything else